# Compiling C program using XCode

Tags: c, xcode

i am trying to run a very simple C program using XCode which is typed below

```
1)   #include <stdio.h>
2)   int main ()
3)   {
4)     printf("Hello, World!\n");
5)     func();
6)     return 0;
7)   }
8)   void func()
9)   {
10)    printf("xxxx");
11)  }
```

In line number 5 i am getting warning "Implicit declaration of func is invalid in c99" and in line number 8 i am getting an error "conflicting types for func"

please advise
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `func();` before using it (in main),  otherwise it is declared as a function that returns `int`, and when the compiler gets to line 8, it sees a different declaration of the same function that returns `void`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(void);
int main ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error messages tell you exactly what is wrong. Functions being used must be declared first, either in the same source code unit, or in a header file.

If `func()` is not declared yet, the compiler assumes an `int` result.

The first error says you should declare `func()` before using it:

```
void func(void);

int main()
{
    etc...
```

The second error tells you that `func()` does not return `int` after all. If you had declared `func()` first, both errors wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Well, in old, really old C, this was not necessary, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

you called `func()` before declaring or defining, that's why.

add `void func();` before main